# grep operation with " ? " pattern

Tags: bash

I am going thru with different grep option. and I have following grep command

```
result=$(echo "ABC DEF" | grep -q " ? ")
```

I know, `-q` option in grep will silent the output.

Does `" ? "` have specific meaning in `grep` command or it will just match `" ? "` as string/characters?

Comment: So my understanding is correct, that it will match just " ? " inside pipeline output of first command. Thanks.

Comment: `grep -q` never prints anything, so `result` will always be the empty string.  You are in fact probably looking for `if echo "ABC DEF" | grep -q " ? "; then echo "Matched"; else echo "No match"; fi` where the entire and sole purpose of the `if` flow control command is to run a command pipeline and examine its exit status.

Comment: Correct. Your assignment doesn't give you hints about the question you're trying to answer.

Comment: @tripleee So if code that is posted in comment i am going to execute, it will give "No Matched" as output. As this condition if echo "ABC DEF" | grep -q " ? "; is going to false.

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  This is easy to verify on your own, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With no flags to indicate the input is a regex, it has no special meaning.

Test:

```
~$ echo "hello ? world" | grep " ? "
hello ? world
```

Test with the `-q` flag:

```
~$ echo "hello ? world" | grep -q " ? "; echo $?
0
```

`$?` holds the exit status of the *last* command. `grep` was the last command before `echo`, and it returns 0 when it matches.

If you try a non-matching string, you'll get:

```
~$ echo "hello world" | grep -q " ? "; echo $?
1
```